# Define $interval on a AngularJS controller with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I am a complete newbie when it comes to CoffeeScript and AngularJS, and now I'm in over my head trying to learn the two simultaneously.

I have a AngularJS controller that is firing a $http request to read a value. This CoffeeScript is working fine:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []).controller('SalesTodayCtrl', [
        '$scope','$http'
        ($scope, $http) ->
        $http.get('http://myserver/sales/today/count').success (data) ->
            $scope.salesToday = data ])
```

Now I need this controller to be refreshed each minute. Could anyone provide me with a concrete code example on how to do so? With as little pseudo code as possible.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, I'd define an update method on your controller:

```
$scope.url = 'http://myserver/sales/today/count'

$scope.success = (data) ->
  $scope.salesToday = data

$scope.update = () ->
  $http.get($scope.url).success $scope.success
```

Then make a service to handle the 'every minute' bit. You can make use of the Angular provided [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service.

```
app.service 'Refresh', ($interval) ->
  @every = (update, ms) ->
    $interval update, ms
```

Finally, inject the `Refresh` service into controller and call it with your update function.

```
app.controller 'SalesTodayCtrl', ($scope, $http, Refresh) ->
  # ... the other code
  Refresh.every $scope.update, 60000
```

This uses `setInterval` as the underlying mechanism, but because it's being used through Angular's interval wrapper, you don't need to worry about triggering digests manually.

If you need the refresh to happen at exactly 1 minute intervals, then you will probably run into `setInterval` [issues](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).  You probably want to look into doing delta time using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, both of you helped me on my way, here. Couldn't quite get the services right due to my extreme newbieness, but ended up with a combination of the two suggestions. If I could hand out a green checkmark to both of you, I would have!

Answer (score 0):

Just a pseudo code. I didn't test it, but sure it should work

```
countUp = ->
  $http.get('http://myserver/sales/today/count').success (data) ->
    $scope.salesToday = data
  return

$timeout countUp, 500
```